# How to calculate Euclidian distance when arrays have different dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to compute Euclidian distance step by step. Since Euclidian distance is: Dsqr = S+R-2*G, I am calculating each element separately.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
# Create X matrix
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
Z = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])


# Calculate G from X using inner product
G = np.inner(X,Z)
print(G)


# Calculating S
def calculate_S(X, n, m):
    assert n == X.shape[0]
    assert m == X.shape[0]
    S = np.diag(np.inner(X,X))[:,None]
    S = S.repeat(3,axis=1)
    print("shape of S at the end ={}".format(S.shape))
    return S

n,d1=X.shape
m,d2=X.shape
S= calculate_S(X,n,m)
print(S)


# Calculating R
def calculate_R(Z, n, m):
    R = np.inner(Z,Z)
    R = np.diag(np.inner(Z,Z))[None,:]
    R = R.repeat(2,axis=0)
    print("shape of R at the end ={}".format(R.shape))
    return R

n,d1=Z.shape
m,d2=Z.shape
R = calculate_R(Z, n, m)
print(R)


# calcuate Dsqr
def l2distance(X,Z=None):
    if Z is None:
        Z=X;
    n,d1=X.shape
    m,d2=Z.shape
    assert (d1==d2),
    return S+R-2*G

Dsqr = l2distance(X,Z)
print(Dsqr)
```

And this works on with arrays in example I have.
Now, when I switch the values for my X and Y to be:

```
X = np.random.rand(700,100)
Z = np.random.rand(800,100)
```

I am unsure how to reshape the arrays in order to make the above functions work.
I have done a bunch of research and everywhere I find examples where two arrays are simple and match exactly in their dimensions.

So, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Think about distances:

- the distance from your base camp to peak of Mount Everest on a 2-dimensional map X is one thing
- in the real world situation Z it is 3-dimensional and so it is an other thing

I think it is more appropriate to use the content of your data to find the adaption between the differnet dimensions than to do it by an algorithm.